# PySpark - partitionBy to S3 handle special character

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a column called `target_col_a` in my dataframe with Timestamp value which have been casted to String e.g. `2020-05-27 08:00:00`.

I then `partitionBy` this column as per below.

```
target_dataset \
    .write.mode('overwrite') \
    .format('parquet') \
    .partitionBy('target_col_a') \
    .save('s3://my-bucket/my-path')
```

However, my s3 path turns out like `s3://my-bucket/my-path/target_col_a=2020-05-27 08%3A00%3A00/part-0-file1.snappy.parquet`

Is there a way to output the partition without the `%3A` and retain `:`?

Note: when I use Glue native `DynamicFrame` to write to S3 or Redshift `UNLOAD` to S3 the partitioning comes as desired (without the `%3A` and with `:`) e.g.

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = target_dataset,
    connection_type = "s3",
    connection_options = {
        "path": "s3://my-bucket/my-path/",
        "partitionKeys": ["target_col_a"]},
    format = "parquet",
    transformation_ctx = "datasink2"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't.

Pyspark uses hadoop client libraries for input and output. These libraries create paths using the [Java URI package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html). Spaces and colons are not valid URI characters, so they're [URL encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) before writing. Pyspark will handle the decoding automatically when the dataset is read, but if you want to access the datasets outside of Spark or Hadoop, you'll need to [URL decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) the column values.

Answer (score 1):

Specially characters like spaces  and `:` cannot be part of any S3 URI.
Even if some how manage to create one you would face difficulties later on every time you use them.

Better to replace these character with URI acceptable ones.

You should follow the key name convention described in this paragraph called [Object Key Guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-key-guidelines) of Amazon S3.

*The following character sets are generally safe for use in key names:*

**Alphanumeric characters** `[0-9a-zA-Z]`

**Special characters** `!, -, _, ., *, ', (, and )`